# Exponent sign not working, only double star instead, why?

Tags: solidity, math

Might be a stupid question. I have checked this many times, it seems as if *only* the following statement works:

```
value = (n**2+n)/2;
```

And not:

```
value = (n^2+n)/2;
```

Since it gives unexpected, strangely low and volatile results.

Although there are sources on the net which show usage with `^` like [this](https://soliditytips.com/articles/basic-math-operations-solidity/#exponential-in-solidity). I finally found out that [only `**` is right](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10475/power-operations-in-solidity). Is it possible that the `^` still works in some situations or is this just an error of some documentations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the latest [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#integers) there are both operation for integers available:

`**` - exponentiation

`^` - bitwise exclusive or

So in your case only `**` makes sense.

I am not aware of any version where this was different.